# Is there any way to findout unused var and functions in angular project

Tags: angular

I am using tslint for identify dead code in my angular project but the problem with tslint is it only identify unused functions and var with access modifiers,In my project at several places we write functions and var without access modifier. What is the correct way to identify unused var and functions??

Answer (score 0):

On your machine installed VS Code tslint extension. it will help you to findout unused var and functions in your angular project.

[image]

Comment: i have done that,but it is not showing unused var and fun which are declare without access modifiers.